# Access Magento 2 session data outside of Magento

Tags: magento-2.1, session

I have Magento 2 installed in a directory at mydomain.com/shop and I want to access the user's session data outside of that folder (specifically user id and isLoggedIn) so I can use it to log them into another app. I set my Magento cookie path to "/" but what code do I need to grab the session from domain.com/file.php?

Comment: Anyone have an idea?

Answer (score 1):

I know this post is old. However I found the way to check if a customer is logged in would be via the below code in Magento 2.1 also the file the below code is in has to reside in your Magento2 directory.

```
<?php
     use Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap;

     /*** If your external file is in root folder ****/
     require __DIR__ . '/app/bootstrap.php';

     $params = $_SERVER;
     $bootstrap = Bootstrap::create(BP, $params);
     $obj = $bootstrap->getObjectManager();
     $state = $obj->get('Magento\Framework\App\State');
     $state->setAreaCode('frontend');


     $customerSession = $obj->get('Magento\Customer\Model\Session');
     if($customerSession->isLoggedIn()){
         echo 'Logged in';
     }else{
         echo 'Not logged in';
     }
```

Comment: This seems to be work only if the file is placed inside the Magento Root directory. Outside it may not work.

Answer (score 0):

Magento Customer session won't work outside the Magento. But you can trigger a login success event and set customer id to any cookie and can get anywhere in the browser. I did same since my scenario was same as mentioned by you.